# Why will visual studio 2015 only allow me to use 50% of 1 core?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

When making a project I am only using 12.5% (bounces between 12 and 13 so 12.5 seems logical) of my total cpu (4 cores). Therefore my project is only using 50% of one core. I realize parallel threading will use more cores (eg. more total cpu), but why can I not utilize 100% (or close) of one core? Is this a setting in visual studio?

Comment: What do you mean by "_Making a project_"? Maybe you are being limited to something other than the VS. Does your project save to a file for example? You will get limited to disk speed.. etc.

Comment: Do you have an i7 with 8 threads?  If so this is expected for a single threaded application.

Comment: How do you measure CPU usage? I recommend to take a look at Process Explorer (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) because default Task Manager is not always accurate.

Comment: Is your application single threaded?  Does you processor support hyper threading?  If yes to both then you could be using half a core becuase HT splits the core in half.

Comment: You can concurrently build multiple independent *projects* in a Visual Studio solution. A single project, however, is restricted to a single thread for building at any given time. The setting for concurrent projects can be found under Tools/Options, expand "Project and Solutions" in the left tree, then select "Build and Run" under that. The top item on the right-side property sheet is "Maximum number of parallel project builds", and is indeed configurable. Most of this is just a fancy front-end for MSBuild, where the real work is kicked off.

Comment: @drescherjm and NathanOliver both appear to be correct. My cpu does support hyper threading and has 8 threads. Since my program is single threaded it uses one thread (12.5% of my total cpu). Thank you both for pointing this out!!

Comment: Are you using the extra processing power for building projects or are you talking about your executable?  If the executable, Windows is in charge of allocating processor time, not Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

drescherjm and NathanOliver both appear to be correct. My cpu does support hyper threading and has 8 threads. Since my program is single threaded it uses one thread (12.5% of my total cpu). Thank you both for pointing this out!!